# InnoDB: Copying a number of records along with their tag memberships

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, innodb

**Foreign keys might be appropriate to this problem/solution. However, I have inherited this code and db, which do not use foreign keys, and so it would be difficult to add them. If absolutely necessary I can do it, but I'd prefer not to.**

Let's pretend that I have a very simple set of tables in an `InnoDB` database that are used to store a bunch of jokes, each of which belongs to particular group and may have one or more tags associated with it. I am using `PHP/MySQLi` to do the work. Let's say the tables look like so:

```
GROUPS
id (int, primary, auto_inc)  |  group_name (varchar[64])
============================================================
1                               knock, knock jokes
2                               one-liners

JOKES
id (int, primary, auto_inc)  |  group_id (int)  |   joke_text (varchar[255])
=============================================================================
1                               1                   interrupting cow. inte-MOO!

TAGS
id (int, primary, auto_inc)  |  tag_text (varchar[255])
=============================================================================
1                               explicit
2                               hilarious

JOKE_TAGS
id (int, primary, auto_inc)  |  joke_id (int)   |   tag_id (int)
=============================================================================
1                               1                   1
```

*Even though it makes no sense in the context of these jokes*, let's just say that the user has the option to copy the jokes from one group to another. Thanks to users' help on this site, I have figured out that the easiest way to do that would be something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO jokes (group_id,joke_text)
SELECT '$dstGroupID', r2.joke_text FROM jokes AS j2
WHERE j2.group_id = '$srcGroupID';
```

That seems to work just fine. However, I am completely lost as to how I can efficiently copy over the tag memberships. For instance, if I was to copy the `jokes` from `group.id=1` to `group.id=2` (using the sample data shown above), I would want the `JOKE_TAGS` table to look like so:

```
JOKE_TAGS
id (int, primary, auto_inc)  |  joke_id (int)   |   tag_id (int)
=============================================================================
1                               1                   1
2                               2                   1
```

For the life of me, I simply cannot figure out a way to do this without throwing away the SQL above and simply iterating through every single `joke` that is being copied, with the logic looking something like this:

- Pull out a joke's information
- Pull out that joke's tag memberships
- Insert a new record into `JOKES` with the pulled out info from above
- Grab the id of the newly inserted joke
- Insert a new record into `JOKE_TAGS`, using the id grabbed above

This is obviously WILDLY inefficient when compared to the 'copying' SQL listed above. If anyone can suggest a more efficient solution, I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using foreign keys, even if they're not being enforced. What you're describing is a fundamental change in your data structure. Going from 1:1 to 1:n: one joke existing in one group, to one join existing in MULTIPLE groups.

As such, the normal fix would be to move that `group_id` field out of the `jokes` table and into a link table:

```
jokes <-> joke_groups <-> groups
```

in which case, a simple "copy" would involve inserting a new record in the link table:

```
 (joke #1, group #7) // existing joke/group link
 (joke #1, group #3) // "copying" the joke into group #3
```

If you CAN'T change the schema to accomodate the change in structure, then you will have to manually copy the joke around:

```
 a) get contents of joke record
 b) insert copied data back into joke record to create a NEW joke
 c) get ID of new record
 d) copy all tags from old id, insert with new linkages to new joke's ID
```

normally this'd be as simple as a couple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`-type queries, but MySQL does not let you select from the same table as you're inserting into, so a round-trip through the client is required.

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the copied joke will require its own record, as it needs to be able to be edited separately from the 'original'. So changing the schema isn't an option (although I had never even considered that). I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "a round-trip through the client is required". Could you possibly expand on that a bit? Thanks.

Comment: select the joke record's contents into a php array or whatever, then  use that array for an `INSERT` query. e.g. literally suck the joke data over to PHP, then stuff it back into the database - a round-trip through the client.

Comment: Right, so if I was copying over 100 jokes from one group to another then I would need to do 100 `SELECT` and `INSERT` calls. Correct? It's awful to think that there are no alternatives to such an inefficient approach.

Comment: well, one select call, if you can do a `select .. .where joke_id in (1,2,3,4,5....)`, then do the inserts in a loop. But yeah, that's the only practical option, since you really do need to make copies of the records.